How initialize List Collection
I need to initialize a list for generating polygons. I have this example:
List<List<Point>> test = List.of(List.of(
                Point.fromLngLat(11.079581683351336, 40.806539350413004),
                Point.fromLngLat(11.0800563434953, 40.806358652993936),
                Point.fromLngLat(11.080342283340997, 40.80669836356384),
                Point.fromLngLat(11.079844748009634, 40.806846534421396),
                Point.fromLngLat(11.07961027733569, 40.80679232562545),
                Point.fromLngLat(11.079581683351336, 40.806539350413004)
));

Its is ok, but when i try initialize:
List<List<Point>> latLngPoints = new ArrayList<>();

# In loops example: 
latLngPoints.add(List.of(Point.fromLngLat(latLng.longitude, latLng.latitude)));
# ....

I don't get multi array, how to properly initialize this type of array liste?

What do you mean with "I don't get multi array"? You do, you have a List<List<Point>>. If you want your inner list to have multiple elements, you have to specify them – currently your inner list only holds a single item.

you need something like List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>()); latLngPoints.add(points); and in loop points.add(Point.fromLngLat(...)) || but I wonder why you need a list of list (with only one list)

be aware that List.of() returns an unmodifiable list, while ArrayList of course is modifiable

Your first initialization is ok
List<List<Point>> latLngPoints = new ArrayList<>();

You have created a List of Lists.
In the next step, I assume you will iterate over some "latLng" array/List.
So you can use something like that. In for loop create a new List object, add all points and add a List to latLngPoints.
final List<List<Point>> latLngPoints = new ArrayList<>();

for (Polygon polygon : allPolygons) {
  final List<Point> polygonPoints = new ArrayList<>();
  for (LongLang longLang : polygon.getPoints()) {
    polygonPoints.add(new Point ...);
  }
  latLngPoints.add(polygonPoints);
}

Hope it will help.
It is hard to understand from your question what are initial values to operate with.

If a question is unclear, you should leave a comment asking for clarification, and you might want to consider vote-to-close with some flavour of 'this question lacks details or focus'. Instead of trying something random. The point of SO (and we can debate how successful it is at this) is that each page is a wikipedia-esque resource for the ages. Consider the question and this answer - if someone finds this with a web search, is it useful? It mostly isn't.

You can use double-brace initialization for creating multi-dimensional collections. Here's an example:
List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new ArrayList<>() {{
        add(new Object());
    }});
    
    add(new ArrayList<>() {{
        add(new Object());
    }});
}};


This is a terrible way to initialise, as it defines a new anonymous class for the outer ArrayList, and one per add - and of course an instance of each one of those classes.

Double brace initialization is bad, and no one should do it.  Your example does not create an ArrayList;  it creates an object whose class is an anonymous subclass of ArrayList, with an embedded reference to the object in whose method the initialization occurred, which prevents that owner object from being garbage collected.
